# Error al intentar conectarme a Access desde vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Lo que estoy probando es como insertar datos en access desde vb.net.

Por lo que tengo hice un formulario de prueba con 2 campos más un botón guardar.

Este es el código que realice.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim conexion As OleDbConnection
Dim comandos As OleDbCommand

Dim StrConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Y:\db\TestDB.accdb"

Private Sub btnEnviar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnviar.Click
    Try
        comandos = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Tabla1 (campo1, campo2) VALUES (txtCampo1, txtCampo2)", conexion)
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo1", txtCampo1.Text)
        comandos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo2", txtCampo2.Text)

        comandos.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Guardado correctamente", vbInformation, "Correcto")

        txtCampo1.Clear()
        txtCampo2.Clear()
        txtCampo1.Focus()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al guardar", vbExclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        conexion.ConnectionString = StrConnection
        conexion.Open()
        MsgBox("Conexión exitosa!", vbInformation, "Correcto")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Se ha producido un error al conectarse a DB" + ex.ToString, vbExclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSalir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click
    'conexion.Close()
    MsgBox("Desconectado", vbInformation, "Correcto")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Lo que recibo al intentar conectarme es un DBSystem.NullReferenceException. Al principio pensé que no tenia acceso a la Base de datos, pero hice pruebas de conexión y si tengo acceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Luippo,

Tienes que instanciar la conexión ya que ahora mismo no la estas instanciando, y entonces te salta la excepción cuando le añades alguna propiedad:

```
Dim conexion As OleDbConnection 'Aqui solo estás declarando conexion como tipo OleDbConnection pero no la estas instanciando'

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        conexion = new OleDbConnection() 'Instanciamos la conexión'
        conexion.ConnectionString = StrConnection
        conexion.Open()
        MsgBox("Conexión exitosa!", vbInformation, "Correcto")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Se ha producido un error al conectarse a DB" + ex.ToString, vbExclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,  perdón por no darme cuenta antes Y-Y